# Issue while running Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run the example of Oozie that comes with Cloudera Sandbox (cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-vmware).

I extracted oozie-examples.tar.gz that was in /usr/share/doc/oozie-3.3.2+92

As shown in Apache Oozie link, I tried to run the Oozie but no success
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_Examples.html

```
[cloudera@localhost oozie-3.3.2+92]$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run

Error: E0901 : E0901: Namenode [localhost:8020] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelist
```

oozie-site.xml looks like:

less /etc/oozie/conf.dist/oozie-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
<value> </value>
<description>
Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
<value> </value>
<description>
Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
</description>
</property>
```

job.properties looks like:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any changes I need to make on setting files?

I had several unsuccessful attempts. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rio

PS 
I am new to Oozie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these properties in core-site.xml for impersonation in order to solve your whitelist error

```
  <property> 
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name> 
  <value>*</value> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name> 
  <value>*</value> 
  </property>
```